# I.E Jquery Menu Bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, menu

Hello helpfull people.

I am experiencing a really painful IE bug in IE 10 and 9

if you click the right hand menu jquery will trigger it to pop out, from here there are four different sections also when clicked will display and hide the others. HOWEVER IE is not hiding the others once one is clicked OR displaying the two middle sections.

Below is the jquery script:

$(document).click(function (a) {
        $(a.target).is("#nav_container *, #menu_button") || $("body").hasClass("nav-active") && (
                $("body").removeClass("nav-active"), $("#nav_container").removeClass("about_active"), $("#nav_container").removeClass("clients_active"),$("#nav_container").removeClass("services_active"), $(".page_container").addClass("no-scale"))
    });

```
$("#nav_about").click(function (a) {
    $("#nav_container").addClass("about_active");
});

$("#nav_about_close").click(function (a) {
    $("#nav_container").removeClass("about_active"); 
    $("#nav_container").removeClass("contact_active");
    $("#nav_container").removeClass("clients_active"); 
    $("#nav_container").removeClass("services_active"); 
    $(".page_container").addClass("no-scale");
})

$("#nav_contact").click(function (a) {
    $("#nav_container").addClass("contact_active");
});
```

I am so stumpped with this. If some kind person could shed some insight into what may be causing this I will forever be great full..!!!

Comment: You need to post the code here, not as a link to a production website. When you get the solution, you'll fix the website, how will future readers of the question know what the problem was?

Comment: what kind of ie do you need? ie9 or ie8 ?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML (especially all end tags exist), invalid HTML often causes problems like this in IE.